# How to post an image to a facebook page from a PHP app?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to post an image to a facebook page from a PHP app. I check many resources, the documentation, some demo codes and several questions in this site, but cannot finish a working app.

Here is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$post_url = '/443513955707619/photos';

$msg_body = array(
                'source' => '@/www/www.gbart.hu/public_html/facebook/megosztos_app/img/winner/winner_'.(int)$round[0].'.jpg',
                //'image' => 'http://www.gbart.hu/facebook/megosztos_app/img/winner/winner_'.(int)$round[0].'.jpg',
                'message' => 'http://www.facebook.com/WangMesterKinaiKonyhaja/app_322145727882829',
                'access_token' => $access_token
                );
try {
    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body);
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here are my permissions for the app:
$fbPermissions = 'email, publish_actions, publish_stream, photo_upload, manage_pages';

I have the appID, app_secret, access_token parameters as required (the other parts of the app is working).

I got some different error messages, like invalid album id or invalid access tokens. I solved these, and now there isn't any error messages, but the photo does not appear anywhere.

In a previous version of this code I tried to post the image to the page walls not to the album, but that made a weird result: posted the image to my user profile's wall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post something like below

```
$url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/443513955707619/photos?access_token=".$token."&message=hello&url=http://imagetopost.com/hi.jpg&method=post";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I tried this, but no new image appears in the album.
Respone contains the following: {"id":"443775505681464"}

Comment: this response means the photo is uploaded successfully